# Julia: Global variable in a module

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a module in Julia which has a variable incremented each time one of its function is called.

```
module A

a = 0

export get_and_increment_a

function get_and_increment_a()
    a = a + 1
    return a
end

end

using .A
println(get_and_increment_a())
println(get_and_increment_a())
```

I would expect that the prinln() give me

1

2

But I have the following error message:

```
UndefVarError: a not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] get_and_increment_a() at ./In[1]:8
 [2] top-level scope at In[2]:2
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have not used Julia before, but it seems that you export `get_a` but provide no definition for it. Instead, you provide a definition for `get_and_increment_a`.

Comment: Also you need to write `global a = a + 1` as otherwise the function definition will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The variable was not previously declared, if you want to use without declaring such a variable, you have to import from some library or just declare in another file and import to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Move a = 0 inside the function body.  All variables inside are local only.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope